# How can I pass an argument to a Tkinter `bind` callback?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from Tkinter import *

def keypress(key):
    print key, "pressed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.bind('<Return>', keypress(key="enter"))
   root.bind('a', keypress(key="a"))
   root.mainloop()
```

I realize the function is being called as soon as the program starts; how can I make it pass the arguments to the keypress function without invoking it immediately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `bind` function calls, you are actually calling the functions  and then binding the result of the function (which is `None`) . You need to directly bind the functions. On solution is to `lambda` for that.

Example -

```
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event: keypress(key="enter"))
root.bind('a', lambda event: keypress(key="a"))
```

If you want to propagate the `event` parameter to the `keypress()` function, you would need to define the parameter in the function and then pass it. Example -

```
def keypress(event, key):
    print key, "pressed"
...
root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: keypress(event, key="enter"))
root.bind("a", lambda event: keypress(event, key="a"))
```

Comment: Yeah I knew what it was doing, I just didn't know how to fix it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes I am actually, sorry hang on I'll put the updated code in the question.

Comment: The lambda also needs to take an argument, i have updated the code, try now.